# How to update JSONobject if a EditText content change?

Tags: android, json, android-edittext

I retrieve some phones and emails of a contact via JSONarray, for every one of this elements it creates a new EditText (with the phone or email).

I want to know how to update my JSONobject if user change the phone number, or an email, after that I want to add this JSONobject's to a JSONarray to post to my service.

This is the code where I put elements in EditText's:

```
try {
                multiplesArray = new JSONArray(multiples);
                //multiplesUpdatedArray = new JSONArray();
                System.out.println(multiplesArray.toString(2));

                for (int i=0; i<multiplesArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject contact = new JSONObject();
                    String type = multiplesArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("tipo");
                    String data = multiplesArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("texto");
                    String id = multiplesArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");

                    if (type.equals("phone")) {
                        final EditText etPhoneItem = new EditText(this);
                        etPhoneItem.setText(data);
                        viewPhonesContainer.addView(etPhoneItem);

                    } else if (type.equals("email")) {
                        final EditText etEmailItem = new EditText(this);
                        etEmailItem.setText(data);
                        viewEmailContainer.addView(etEmailItem);

                    }

                    contact.put("tipo", type);
                    contact.put("id", id);
                    contact.put("texto", data);
                    contact.put("cat", "");
                    contact.put("cat_id", "");

                    /*multiplesUpdatedArray.put("tipo");
                    multiplesUpdatedArray.put(type);
                    multiplesUpdatedArray.put("id");
                    multiplesUpdatedArray.put(id);
                    multiplesUpdatedArray.put("texto");
                    multiplesUpdatedArray.put(data);*/
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I try some code with "setOnFocusChangeListener" but it didn't work :-(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addTextChangeListener` .

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence pCode, int start, int before, int count) {
                // change your JSONObject
                jsobObject.put("key",  "value");
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it.

```
 etPhoneItem.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() != 0) {
                try {
                    contact.put("number", s.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use `textView.addTextChangedListener(yourTextWatcherListener)` to get the text when user changes the text. But why update that text in json frequetly, because using TextWatcher you will endup updating the json for each and every character you enter. Updating json frequently is very expensive and very bad practice. Instead of using textwatch listener just form the json when you press the post button.

If you are very clear that you are going to update it frequently, then create pojo classes according to the json structure. Updating the variables of the class is not expensive. Convert the pojo class to json using **[Jackson](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/)** when editing is done.

**[JSON to POJO](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)**